# Failed audit for a question that should be closed

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

Why should this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6920022) not be closed?

I got this as an audit, which I failed. I voted to close the question, as

- It is not a programming question (ok, it asks for an algorithm, maybe it should go to Programmers?)
- It shows no effort to solve this issue at all
- It isn't very clear without the comments
- (It smells like homework, as stated in the comments)

Usually I would just skip over the failed audit when I'm convinced that I am right in my decision. However, I recently failed a lot of audits I strongly disagree with (usually in the Triage queue), so I decided to start disputing them.

1. What do you think? Am I wrong in my assumptions? Why is this particular question a candidate for an audit?
2. Is there some better way to dispute audits then on meta, i.e. without using the meta-effect?

Comment: in reopen and close audits, single vote down or close would suffice to [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773) so that these stop bringing next reviewers in trouble

Comment: Dollars to donuts that this question was hand-picked to be an audit post.  It was a problem posted at a contest.  For programmers, not accountants or coffee drinkers.  This is what scares me about the Triage queue, it will just produce bone, no meat left.

Comment: Why exactly is the cited question off-topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's take your objections in turn:

> It is not a programming question (it asks for an algorithm)

Algorithmic questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow.  Algorithms are even cited in the Help Center/On-Topic article.

> It shows no effort to solve this issue at all

Lack of effort is not a valid close reason.

> It isn't very clear without the comments

On the clarity scale, I'd say it probably ranks in the top 5% of all questions asked on Stack Overflow, so maybe you just don't understand the question or don't have the necessary background knowledge.

> It smells like homework

Homework questions are allowed on Stack Overflow.

> It belongs on Programmers

No, it doesn't.  Even if it did, that's not a valid reason for closing a question.

Comment: `Lack of effort has never been a prerequisite for asking questions on Stack Overflow.`  The help center says otherwise.  One of the very first things mentioned in "how to ask" is that questions should be well researched.  I could also see the question being closed as Too Broad, given that it's a requirements dump asking for a full solution (Although I'm on the fence on whether it crosses the line).

Comment: Yes, but lack of effort is not a close reason, nor is lack of research (although it is a downvote reason).    No close reason means it's not a requirement; it's a suggestion.

Comment: I'm well aware that it's not a reason to close, but that's not what your answer says.  It should probably say something like, "lack of effort is only reason to downvote a post, it is not a reason to close it" or something like that.

Comment: The mechanics are not important.  Prior research or demonstration of effort is not a requirement for asking questions on Stack Overflow, and never was.  Note your use of the word "should" in your comment above, not "must."

Comment: While true, it's a pretty strong *should*.  We don't want questions like that asked here, to the point that we actually rate-limit/ban people from asking questions if they start to ask a lot of questions with those problems.  That section of the answer is, if not incorrect, at least incomplete.  Rather than saying, "it's not a problem" it should really just say, "closing isn't the right way to deal with questions with that kind of problem, voting is".  While "effort" isn't technically a mandated requirement; we work *very* hard here to get rid of (or improve) low quality questions.

Comment: @Servy: Better? ...

Comment: Yes, that's better.

Comment: Well, thanks for the clarifications... So in a nutshell: it is a bad question, but technically okay - I should vote it down, but not close it.

Comment: I don't even think it's a bad question.  Compare it to the endless parade of highly-localized, under-specified troubleshooting questions that we get all day long; questions that are usually only of interest to the person asking them.